# My Secondary HDD Disappeared At First, And Now Its Barely Working

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I have a couple of HDD in my PC, one of them is a 3TB secondary drive "T" that I keep all my media in.

today, I notice that drive "T" has disappeared, it wasn't showing either in (my computer) or (disk manager).

I rebooted my PC and a message showed up "sata secondary hard disk drive 1 failure", there were a couple of option, either to continue or to diagnose the drive, I selected "diagnose", it went on for about "5 minutes" then said there's an error in the drive. It gave me 2 options, to continue scanning or boot windows, I booted.

After booting it I immediately went to "my computer" and the drive "T" was there, I can open it, but it is extremely slow, and the file (media) would hang up when I open them.

I rebooted the PC again, the message came up again "sata secondary hard disk drive 1 failure", I scanned again, this time it didn't find anything wrong, and it asked me again if I want to continue scanning, and I did, which went on for almost 30 min, and didn't find anything wrong.

Now the drive is there and I can see my stuff in it, but when I play them, it is barely working and cant seek forward/backward because when I do the software will hang up.

What can I do to save my HDD? if I can't, then what can I do to save my data?

The HDD is a Seagate 3TB, and I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate.

**I'm trying to transfer my data to another HDD, but its moving at 47KB/s.  I have 1TB of data!!!

- I can't move my data, it keep stopping at 1% *

***Ok, I managed to move 95% of my files via "Roadkil's Unstopable Coppier", I formatted the drive. and it seems to be working fine, but when I restart my PC it still show the same error. so how do I make sure the drive is broken ? ***

Comment: The HDD is dying. Backup the data on it or transfer the data to a new drive, if you can in it's current state.

Comment: Not a single question mark. :)

Comment: @techie007 what?

Comment: @joeqwerty Or the controller is failing.  I've had a drive keep flaking out--and I eventually realized it was the controller, not the drive.  The drive hasn't errored since I moved it to another port, the device I put on it's port is unusable due to the errors.

Comment: It could be the controller but my bet is on the HDD.

Comment: What is the controller, and how can I check?

Comment: It's failing;  the longer you fool around with it, the less likelihood that you'll save anything on it.  Copy targeted folders ASAP -- not the entire drive, just the folders you want most.  Odds are clearly highest that it'st he drive itself failing, but diagnose AFTER you recover what data you can.

Comment: I can't move them, it stops at 1%-15%